# Deleted by the gatherer SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

My site crawling was ok but suddenly it crawled only few pages. When check the history it showed deleted by the gatherer.

After that I did the reset index and I did the full crawl again but still it shows same old crawled count only.

But my other websites crawling is fine

What can the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

this error is possible if multiple crawls running at the same time can lead to a collision with the results getting put into the search index, if this happens too often the content will be removed as being unseen.  There is a 3 day limit on keeping results, if the content is not found again within that time then it will be removed.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ba16fdf9-55b4-47a5-8a1c-e15a2c5ba525/deleted-by-the-gatherer-messages-in-the-crawl-log

Comment: Thanks for the reply I did restart the search server and did the Index reset but still not showing all the pages. Earlier I specified the sitemap `url` in the content source. Since it’s not working now, I specified all the `URLs` in the content source which is working. But I want to use the sitemap `URL` as earlier.